# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{k^2+a^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to take the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{k^2+a^2}$. I know what the answer is (something like $e^{-|x|}$), but I'm having trouble actually doing the integral in the inverse Fourier transform.

First I noted that $\frac{1}{k^2+a^2}$ is *even* in $k$, so it's inverse Fourier transform is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+a^2} \cos(kx) dk$$

Where do I go from here? I tried integration by parts, but that didn't lead anywhere. And looking at the Fourier transform of  $e^{-|x|}$ didn't really help.

Ideas?

Comment: In order to write a pertinent answer, do you know about Contour Integration?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't.

Comment: $\cos (k x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-i k x}+\frac{1}{2} e^{i k x}\quad$ maybe this helps